# squid multi instance: squid is already running

Tags: squid

I'm trying to run several instances of squid on the same system.

The system: Ubuntu 12.04

Squid version: 3.4.4 stable

This version isn't in ppa repos yet, so I've compiled it.

I have two config files: explicit.conf and hidden.conf
The first hide X-forwarded-for http header, the second don't

I start squid like that:

```
squid -f /etc/squid/hidden.conf -d 1 -N
```

arguments used only for test:

-d to show errors

-N to don't run squid as deamon

And the second instance is launched like that:

```
squid -f /etc/squid/explicit.conf -d 1 -N
```

But this command returns: `Squid is already running!  Process ID XXXX`

I thought the two instances are working on the same log file and that should create an error, so I added `access_log daemon:/var/log/access-explicit.log squid`
And the same thing for hidden instance

But anything works.

According the squid doc I'm in the right way.

Anybody have similar errors ?

Thx
(and sorry for this bad english)

Comment: Have you changed the ports, the paths to log file and the pid file?

Comment: And the cache path of course.

Comment: yep, `access_log`, `cache_store_log` and `cache_log` are different in each config file.
Cache config is:
`cache deny all` and `cache_dir null /tmp`

Comment: I just switch from `cache_dir null /tmp` to `cache_dir null/tmp/X` and got the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the error

According the squid doc (http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/CompilingSquid#Debian.2C_Ubuntu) I have configure Squid with:

```
--with-pidfile=/var/run/squid.pid
```

Two solutions to fix that

- Re-compile Squid without `--with-pidfile` argument (not tested, but should works)
- Add `pid_filename /var/run/squid-X.pid` in the config file used.

And voilà :)

(thx to jockot3 from irc for the pid_filename tips)

Comment: What's the meaning of `squid-X`? My config file shows the default is `pid_filename /var/run/squid.pid`